# Display images from url in database

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring, database

I have a MySQL database, in a table I store a link to an image that is located on AWS S3. This images in the database is tied to a specific user who registered.

I need to display images (3 photos in a row), the links of which are in my database. That is, when I add a link, I need this image to be added to the page.

In the program I use Java, Spring, Thymeleaf, HTML (for displaying pages).

Thanks in advance to everyone!

[image: Screenshot of the table in database]

Image Entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "image")
public class Image {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "image_link")
private String imageLink;

public Image() {
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Image{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", imageLink='" + imageLink + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

Comment: what have you done so far???

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt I've just created entity of this table. and then idk how to show images.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do so, but ultimately you need to pass your image url to your browser and you use html `<img>` tag to display the image.

For how to get the image url, there are many ways too. You can use ajax, hence this is more on Javascript technique.

If you using `Thymeleaf`, this is more on server side processing, you need to write your display logic in the `Thymeleaf` template, once browser got the html result, your image will be displayed automatically.

Comment: can I add images dynamically using <img> tag? I mean when I add a link to db then this image will appear in this page.

Comment: If you write your logic correctly, once you add a new link to db, and you refresh your browser page, the new image will be displayed of course. `can I add images dynamically using <img> tag?` yes, it will, browser will auto render it if you insert new `<img>` tag.

Comment: But I can't get a bit how can I connect my db table with link and html page to make it dynamically?

Comment: you already have your entity right? that mean you already able to fetch data from db. You just need to iterate through your entity data in `Thymeleaf`, and display the records in `<img>`. Once all these html flush to browser, your image will be displayed.